# Angular: 'sanitizing unsafe URL value' whenever I am trying to point towards a folder withibn

Tags: php, angular

So I am trying to 'fetch' some images from my disk to the Angular application using PHP as backend where I can retrieve my files.

```html
         <ngb-carousel *ngIf="imageNames" class="carousel-fade">
            <ng-template ngbSlide *ngFor="let imagePath of imageNames">
              <img src="{{imagePath}}" height="400px" width="400px">
            </ng-template>
        </ngb-carousel>
```

This is my ts function where I sanitize my url:

```js
getSantizeUrl(url : string) {
    return this.sanitize.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(url);
  }
```

For the note: I am using xampp PhP for getting my link. I have stored my images on 'D:\images' and would like to retreive it.

```php
<?php
    require_once('pdo_img_db.php');
    header('Content-Type: text/plain');

    $part_no = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $image_location = "D:\images";

    $sql = "SELECT FILE_NAME FROM IMAGES WHERE PART_NO_ID=$part_no";
    
    $stmt=$dbh->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();

    $cr =0;
    while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $imageData[$cr] = $image_location.$row['FILE_NAME'];
        $cr++;
    }
    
    $result = $stmt->fetch();

    echo json_encode(["image_data"=>$imageData]);
?>
```

My intention is to store and retrieve the images stored at another place where the server isn't running. For example, I do not want to store it at D:\xampp\htdocs\Quest\images, I want to store it at D:\images. Despite using DomSanitizer function, I still receive the error:

```
WARNING: sanitizing unsafe URL value SafeValue must use [property]=binding *<image-path here>*
```

Answer (score 0):

It is as stated in the error you must do

```
<img [src]="getSanitizeUrl(imagePath)" height="400px" width="400px">
```

wrapping src tag in [ ] makes it a binding property.

Comment: Thanks. While that issue is resolved, seems that I still can't seem to bring my image to the application. The links are still broken. And now I am getting this error ```Security Error: Content at http://localhost:4200/ may not load or link to file:///D:/images/<image-name>.```

Comment: Of course, no matter where you store your images, they must be sent over http and not access from local disk.Since you have php via a web server, you would serve the images from the web server.